# json data from service

Tags: angularjs, json

I have this service call:

```
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/html?conditionId=123&TypeId=100&countryId=1' }).success(function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(obj.ConditionId);
        })
```

The JSON that returns looks something like this.:

> [{"ConditionId":123,"ConditionDescription":"TEXT GOES
>   HERE","ErrorId":0,"DisplayId":0,"DisplayName":"","ErrorValue":""}]

However my alert always responds with undefined.

Comment: Your response is an array. You are threating it as an object. You have to do alert(obj[0].ConditionId)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj` is an array, you are treating as an object.  In order to access that field, you will have to use the following syntax

`obj[0].ConditionId`

The reason you are getting undefined is because the `ConditionId` is not a property of the array.  It belongs to the items *within* the array.

Comment: Ok - that worked - thank you.  I'm going to feel stupid for asking this, but why is obj an array?

Comment: The web service you are making a request to is returning JSON in the form of an array of objects.  In this case, there is only one object in the array, which is why you use `obj[0]` to access it.

The returned response is wrapped in a pair of square brackets `[]`, this is the syntax used to define an array, while the `{}` syntax is used to define objects in JSON.

Comment: Oh yeah...  duh.  Thank you for the response.  I'll accept as soon as it lets me.